# Add or Update Google Calendar Event from Google Sheet with App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a google sheet where each row represents an event I would like on my google calendar. Is it possible to create an App Script that updates an existing event's details if the title and time match, but creates a new event if no match is found? Are there any example codes of how to do this? Thanks

Comment: need more details, even a minimal reproducible example, and details about what to update!

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve, try for instance (cal is your calendar and d the date)

```
const cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
const events = cal.getEventsForDay(d, { search: titre })
let event
if (events.length == 0) { event = cal.createAllDayEvent(titre, d); } else { event = events[0] }
```

then update event